# Defining a Map having Interface as value, declared inside the same Interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to understand Interpreter Design Pattern in Java. I am getting the following code from     [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern). There is written

```
interface Expression {
    public int interpret(Map<String,Expression> variables);
}
```

Could you explain me what is going on here with respect to Expression being the value of Map, which is inside in an Interface of Type Expression. Is it something like recursive calling ? Kindly explain.

Comment: this pattern makes more sense if you have some background on how compilers work.

Comment: the wikipedia link you've provided has a very complete code sample that you should try yourself to see what's happenning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, Yes same function `interpret()` is called again and again but they are not of the same class. Hence it is not actually recursive function.

Used wiki code to explain the Interpreter pattern, but you need to go to and fro to wiki page to understand the whole picture,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern

Interpreter pattern is the one in which each and every variable and the operator in the given expression is represented as a separate class, and then the evaluation happens on the objects of these classes.

Expression - `class, expression - ((y+z)-x)`

In the case of the wiki example which you pointed out, when you call the constructor of Evaluator in the `main()`, only expression will be constructed (again its another Expression object) and saved in the `syntaxTree` reference variable of Evaluator.

To give a gist of whats happening there with expression: `x y z + -`

1. First variables `x,y,z` will be stored as such in the `expressionStack` variable
2. When you encounter `+`, `(y+z)` will be pushed into the `expressionStack`
3. After `-` token, `((y+z)-x)` Expression object will be in the `expressionStack` (check the push and pop which is happening for the operator in `Evaluator`)

so once the constructor of Evaluator is done, you will have Expression object whose implementation is again an Expression denoted as `((y+z)-x)`.

Now comes the interesting part in `main()`, you are substituting values for the variable `(x,y,z)` using `Number` class and it happens in this order,

1. `main () sentence.interpret(variables);`
2. `Evaluator.syntaxTree.interpret(variables);`
3. `Variable.interpret(variables) // Here the actual values(5,10,42) gets substituted for x, y, z.`

and then the `Expression` is evaluated.

If you see `interpret()` of `Variables` class, it is slightly different where it gets the corresponding `Number` object of the variable, using the context passed. This is the actual substitution of variables to numbers using the context object passed in `main()`. This in turn calls the `interpret()` of `Number` which just returns the number and the operation happens as `((10+5)-42) = -27`.

### Advantage:

By using this technique you can keep on adding operations (plus, minus) without affecting the existing operations and one operation is independent of other. It is used in SQL queries and other interpreters.

Thanks,
Prasanna V.

Comment: [Here](http://www.luki.webzdarma.cz/up/ExpEval_Test.zip) is a minimal C++ implementation of expression evaluator, using this pattern. Might help.

Comment: Tx a lot Prasanna V. for the valuable input. Could you provide me with any other URL other than wikipedia where this concept if also explained. Actually I am stuck at the `return variables.get(name).interpret(variables);` and am unable to visualize/comprehend what exactly is going on there.

Comment: Hi Jagvir, Yes that line is the tricky part. "variables" in that return stmt is the context which u are passing in main(). Actually variables.get(name) ~ context.get("x") which is nothing but instance of Number. So it gets drilled down to Number.interpret(variables) which is nothing but the number (5). I think this wiki page itself is a very good example. Hope it helps you ...

Answer (score 1):

An interface defines methods that a class has to implement if it has the interface.

```
class MathExpression implements Expression {
    public int interpret(Map<String,Expression> variables) {
        //insert code here
    }
}
```

I wouldn't describe it as a recursive call. An accurate description is the interface is self-referencing itself in a method call.

```
Expression expression = new MathExpression();
expression.interpret(stringToExpressionMap);
```

The advantage of this is you can define a behavior in that class without having to know the specific implementation of that class.